# How are real skew-symmetric matrices brought to block-diagonal form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am looking for a proof (preferably available online) of the statement that every *real skew symmetric matrix can be brought into block diagonal form, with blocks formed by the pure imaginary eigenvalues*.

I have often come across this statement but it always seems to be taken as a known fact. I would like to see a complete proof.

Thank you

Comment: Do you know about complex Hermitian matrices?  Do you know about the spectral theorem?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom if I'm not mistaken, those are for *diagnoalization*. What I need is block-diagonal, with eigenvalues in blocks (not 1's or -1's).

Comment: That's right, but we can use diagonalization as a stepping stone.  Also, I have no idea what "not 1's or -1's" is supposed to mean here.  I assume you're talking about finding a block diagonal matrix *similar* to your skew-symmetric matrix.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes. Could you maybe provide a reference where I can see the proof? Thank you